# Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError Issue when using Android Support Design NavigationView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, androiddesignsupport, navigationview, android-navigationview

Getting the following issue when using NavigationView on a app:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter

I got the same issue in this sample project:

https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/android5.0/Cheesesquare

Test:

Android 5.1

Extra information:

=====================

Xamarin Studio
Version 5.10.1 (build 6)
Installation UUID: 4f372b0c-765f-463b-9408-1bd0211e4e94
Runtime:
Mono 4.2.1 (explicit/6dd2d0d)
GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)

Package version: 402010102
Xamarin.Profiler
Not Installed

Apple Developer Tools
Xcode 7.2 (9548)
Build 7C68

Xamarin.Mac
Not Installed

Xamarin.Android
Version: 6.0.0.34 (Business Edition)
Android SDK: /Users/rdelrosario/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-mac_x86
Supported Android versions:
2.3 (API level 10)
4.0.3 (API level 15)
4.1 (API level 16)
4.2 (API level 17)
4.3 (API level 18)
4.4 (API level 19)
4.4.87 (API level 20)
5.0 (API level 21)
5.1 (API level 22)
6.0 (API level 23)

SDK Tools Version: 24.4.1
SDK Platform Tools Version: 23.1
SDK Build Tools Version: 23.0.2

Java SDK: /usr
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

Xamarin Android Player
Version: 0.6.5
Location: /Applications/Xamarin Android Player.app

Xamarin.iOS
Version: 9.4.0.0 (Business Edition)
Hash: 7322991
Branch: master
Build date: 2015-12-08 16:20:29-0500

Build Information
Release ID: 510010006
Git revision: 0b60eecdb531933734519c13257d16a780274aab
Build date: 2015-12-04 20:28:20-05
Xamarin addins: 9876fd7c9837977178411ec7375b4352c0a0d6af
Build lane: monodevelop-lion-cycle6-baseline

Operating System
Mac OS X 10.10.5
Darwin Rendys-MacBook-Pro.local 14.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.5.0
Tue Sep 1 21:23:09 PDT 2015
root:xnu-2782.50.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Comment: What version of the support packages are you using?

Comment: Using Version 23.1.1

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Fixed this issue by:

1. Cleaned Solution
2. Deleted projects /bin and /obj folders
3. Deleted Android.Support.Design, Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView and zips folder in path ~/.local/share/Xamarin/
4. Rebuild project

That's it. This forced Xamarin Studio to download and unzip the Android support files again correctly. Will take some time since needs to download the packages, should fix the issue after that.

Comment: This helped me with the similar issue I had with VectorDrawablesCompat in library version 23.4.0.1 on devices API < 21. I got an exception NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat, but when I repeated your steps (I also needed to pay attention to nuget folders left in packages directory and to checking in/undiong pending changes related to packages), I got it working! Yay!

Comment: Thanks a lot! After searching for a fix for quite a while, this is the only one that worked for me (:   My error: Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details> android xamarin