# Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument xamarin android

Tags: java, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

```
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
```

Giving Exception in Android API 18 version 4.3, but it is working in higher version of android. Please give me suggestion to solve this.

Comment: can you post some more details like code and logcat

Comment: It is not creating PdfDocument object. it is throwing exception in the above mentioned. But it is working in higher version of android.

Comment: get idea to solve this from SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34567503/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-issue-when-using-android-support-design-navigatio

Comment: PdfDocument class was added in API 19:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38527965/back-porting-can-use-pdfdocument-api-19-in-jellybean-api-16